# How can i remove rows by condition (initial letters) in r?

Tags: r

```
Date  <- c(2000-01-01, 2000-02-02, ... )   
Abbreviation  <- c("TR_10", "SR_10", "SR_9", "FR_7", "SR_7", ...)       
Value   <- c(1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.8, ... )
Data <- cbind(Date,Abbreviation,Value)
```

How can I remove all rows, which haven't the abbreviation (initial letters) "SR_"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also convert the data to a data frame and simply use `filter()` by the `dpylr` package. In addition to your code, you can have a solution like this:

```
Data <- data.frame(Data)
```

Then assign the filtered data to another dataframe.

```
DataFiltered <- Data %>% filter(Abbreviation %like% "SR_")
```

Similarly, you can use `str_detect()` function from `stringr` package for filtering. This works better, if there is a possibility that Abbreviation has entities having 'SR_' not only as the first 3 characters. You can use RegEx to specify that each entity in filtered data must have Abbreviation starting with 'SR_'.

```
DataFiltered <- Data %>% filter(str_detect(Abbreviation, pattern = "^SR_"))
```

Comment: Where does the `%like%` operator come from?

Comment: `%like%` operator comes from the `data.table` package, again. It is actually a similar form of `grep()` family from base R.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `substr`

```
subset(Data, substr(Abbreviation, 1, 3) == "SR_")
```

#### data

```
Data <- data.frame(Date, Abbreviation, Value, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

```
Data[grep("^SR_",Data[,"Abbreviation"]),]
```